# reading data into unordered_map by multi-thread results in increase of physical memory

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory, unordered-map

I try to write a cache server to load the disk files to memory periodically. The data in the disk files are key-value format, so I adopt the unordered_map as my memory data structure. to avoid the possible read error afterward, I keep two unordered_maps and switch them between writing and reading.
here are my codes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>  
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;

class ProfileSvr{
    public:
        ProfileSvr(int interval_):interval(interval_){
            paths = {"/data/dm/xxx/pz/20220914/data",
                    "/data/dm/xxx/pz/20220915/data",
                    "/data/dm/xxx/pz/20220916/data"};
            cur_pi = 0;
            read_profile_files("/data/dm/xxx/pz/20220916/data"); //commenting this line will result very different memory usage.
        }
        
        void start_timer(){
            std::thread t([=]() {
                while (true) {
                    cout << "Timer:" << ", start runnning ......." << endl;
                    read_profile_files(paths[cur_pi % 3]);
                    cur_pi += 1; 
                    cout << "Timer:" << ", finised runnning ......" << endl;
                    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(this->interval));
                }
            });
            t.detach();
        }
        
        void read_profile_files(string zipped_pdata_path);
        
        int cur_raw_profile_data; 
        inline unordered_map<string, string>& writable_raw_profile_data(){
            if(cur_raw_profile_data == 1){ return raw_profile_data_0;}
            else{ return raw_profile_data_1;}
        }
    public:
        int interval; int cur_pi;
        vector<string> paths;
        unordered_map<string, string> raw_profile_data_0; 
        unordered_map<string, string> raw_profile_data_1;
};

void ProfileSvr::read_profile_files(string zipped_pdata_path){
    vector<string> filenames = {zipped_pdata_path + "/part-00000"};
    istringstream liss;
    string line;
    string id;
    string feature;
    
    unordered_map<string, string>& raw_profile_data = writable_raw_profile_data(); 
    raw_profile_data.clear();
    for (const auto& filename : filenames){
        cout << "reading raw profile :" << filename << endl;
        ifstream infile(filename);
        while (getline(infile, line)){
            liss.clear();
            liss.str(line);
            liss >> id >> feature;
            raw_profile_data[id] = feature;
        } 
    }
    cur_raw_profile_data = (cur_raw_profile_data + 1) % 2;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    ProfileSvr profileSvr(30);
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(30));
    profileSvr.start_timer();
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(3000));
}
```

I observe a mysterious phenomenon: when I load the files by the main thread at startup once and then start the timer thread to load the data twice, the physical memory of the process is about 707128 kb after three disk files are loaded. however, when I only start the timer thread to load thrice, the physical memory of the process is about 240408 kb.

there isn't any race because the timer thread always runs after the main thread. I can't figure out the mechanism for the difference in physical memory.  anyone would help me?

Edit:
I use the top command of Linux to measure the memory consumption of the process. the screenshots are as follows:
the first corresponds that the main thread  loads the data at startup:
[image]
the second corresponds that the main thread  do not load the data at startup:
[image]

Comment: I see no locking or any kind of synchronization, so the whole thing is undefined behavior.

Comment: considering the timer thread always runs after the main thread, and there is a 30 seconds gap between them, so the lock seems unnecessary?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're actually measuring when you say, "physical memory," but when your process starts out, it has vast regions of untouched *virtual* memory. The OS will automatically allocate a new physical page to "back up" a virtual page when your process tries to write into a virtual page for the first time.

Unless you are running processes that are competing for more physical memory than your machine actually has, those physical pages won't ever be given back to the OS until your process terminates.

The `raw_profile_data` map is a local variable in `read_profile_files`. It exists on the stack of whatever thread calls that function.

When you call `read_profile_files` from the constructor, that call happens on the stack of the main thread. When you call it from within the lambda expression in `start_timer`, that call happens on the stack of the new thread. Two different thread stacks in two different virtual memory regions will be "backed up" by different physical pages.

Even if a lot of the map's content is allocated on the heap instead of the stack, chances are good that, for performance reasons, different threads allocate from different VM regions when they allocate heap objects.

Either way, Just because the main thread freed the map that it created, you should not expect that the physical memory where that map once existed will automatically be given back to the OS. Nor should you expect that the maps created by the new thread will be created in the *same* physical memory pages that the main thread used.